# Changing working directories in Linux shell in a C program

Tags: c, linux, shell, directory

My goal is to write a C program that is like a basic shell for Linux. I have everything working except changing working directories. I have tried the `system()` for input strings for `cd` and nothing happened. I also tried `chdir("tokened string")` and also no luck. Anyone have any ideas? This is part of my code:

```
        fgets(cmdStr, sizeof(cmdStr), stdin);

        if( strncmp("quit", cmdStr, 4) == 0 || strncmp("Quit", cmdStr, 4) == 0  )
        {
            break;
        }
        else if( strncmp("cd", cmdStr, 2) == 0 )
        {
            char *token = strtok(cmdStr, " ");
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            chdir(token);
        }
        else
        {
            system(cmdStr);
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to do this? Or is this a simple case of something to do with the child shell not being able to do certain things?

Edit: Code above is complete.

Comment: `chdir` is correct.  What is its return value?  If -1, what is errno?  (Always check return values for system calls.)

Comment: @Nemo the return value is -1 no matter what the string is. Tried multiple times with different strings. Not sure how to check the error that it produces along with -1. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'll just note that the way you're using `strncmp` means that `cdxxx foo` is equivalent to `cd foo`. For more general functionality, parse the string into tokens first and then check whether the first token is `"cd"`. (The question is 5 years old, so this probably isn't relevant, but future readers might be interested.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fgets()` leaves the trailing `'\n'` character in `cmdstr`.

If you type `cd foo`, you'll call `chdir("foo\n")` rather than `chdir("foo")`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `chdir` call is failing with `-1` return value.

Please try to print the `errno` like this:

```
errno = 0;
chdir(token);
if ( errno != 0 ) {
    printf( "Error changing dir: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
}
```

Keith is correct: `\n` at the end is killing you.

You can do following to get rid of it:

```
char *ptr = cmdStr;
<snip>
    else if( strncmp("cd", cmdStr, 2) == 0 )
    {
            strsep(&ptr, " ");       /* skip "cd"   */
            char *chr = strsep(&ptr, "\n");   /* skip "\n"  */
            errno = 0;
            chdir(chr);
            if ( errno != 0 )
               printf( "Error changing dir: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
    }
</snip>
```

Comment: Error changing dir: Unknown error 18446744073709551615

Not sure what this means and google did not help...

Comment: Did some changing around and now im getting this: Error changing dir: No such file or directory

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere. Make sure from your `pwd`, the dir that you trying to `cd` is doable.

Comment: try providing `absolute` path.

Comment: if I type the directory name into the program while it is running I get this: /home
sh: /home: is a directory but typing cd /home doesnt do anything but produce an error. hrmm. Also tried absolute paths.

Comment: I do not have the whole code so don't get what you are saying. If you provide absolute path, what errno are you getting?

Comment: I get the same error as before. However if I change my code to just chdir("/home/name") instead of having the inputted string it will work. so now im thinking it has something to do with the tokenized string. Im going to edit the code up top to be complete.

Comment: @yaegerbomb let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2083/discussion-between-hari-and-yaegerbomb)