# chdir() - no such file or directory

Tags: c, chdir

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char input[150];
  char change[2] = "cd";
  char *directory;

  while(1) {
      prompt();
      fgets(input, 150, stdin);

      if(strncmp(change, input, 2) == 0) {
          directory = strtok(input, " ");
          directory = strtok(NULL, " ");

          printf(directory);
          chdir(directory);
          perror(directory);

      }

      if(feof(stdin) != 0 || input == NULL) {
          printf("Auf Bald!\n");
          exit(3);
      }
  }
}
```

when i start this and type in "cd test" i get "no such file or directory". But there is the directory "test".

Runs on Arch Linux.

Comment: Check your `directory` string like this: `printf("directory = [%s]\n", directory);` in case you have a stray linefeed or other unwanted/invisible characters in the name.

Comment: `char change[2] = "cd"` is assigning an array of size 3 to a variable that is of size 2.  Use `char change[] = "cd"` instead.

Comment: @WilliamPursell- Actually, he is using `strncmp(...2)`, so it is legal, although yours is a good practice anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing Working Directories in linux shell in a C Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920483/changing-working-directories-in-linux-shell-in-a-c-program)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets):

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and
>   stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an
>   EOF or a newline. **If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.**

The problem is there's a newline character `'\n'` at the end of your string that you got from `fgets()`, you need to remove it:

```
fgets(input, 150, stdin);
input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';
```

Also:

```
char change[2] = "cd";
```

That should be `change[3]`, it's 2 (for "cd") + 1 for the NULL terminator `'\0'` which is automatically placed for you.

Then it should work.

**EDIT**:

A different alternative is to change the `strtok()` call such that:

```
directory = strtok(NULL, " \n");
```

This will work if the user enters the string via the enter key or via the EOF (ctrl + d on Linux) character... I'm not sure how likely the second is for a user to do... but it couldn't hurt!

Comment: Shouldn't be better to write `strtok(..., " \n")`, just in case the string ends with an EOF, or something?

Comment: @rodrigo - Yes, that would be better if there was an EOF. I guess I was assuming the user would type "cd <file name> <enter key>" rather than "cd <file name> <ctrl + d>"... but you never know! Edited the answer to cover that.

Comment: And why to limit to `" \n"` and not `" \t\n\r"`, just for fun?